# MySQL Error: Sort aborted

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL 5.1 on Windows 2008 which has 8G Memory.
The error occured every two seconds on Event Viewer.
The error is

D:\SW\MySQL\MySQL server 5.1\bin\mysqld: Sort aborted.

does anyone see this error?

Comment: See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36022

Answer (score 23):

There are at least a few known things to cause this message:

- Insufficient disk space in tmpdir prevented tmpfile from being created.
- Insufficient memory for sort_buffer_size to be allocated.

  Somebody ran KILL in the middle of a filesort.

  The server was shutdown while some queries were sorting.

  A transaction got rolled back or aborted due to lock wait timeout or deadlock.

  Unexpected errors, such as source table or even tmp table was corrupt.

  Processing of a subquery failed which was also sorting.

Check these, and I bet your issue will be resolved.

Comment: could you please share the reference to the docs somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have enough free disk space that MySQL can write to. 'Sort aborted' commonly occurs when there is no disk space left.