# MYSQL sort aborted

Tags: mysql

Hello I have encountered Sort aborted error on one of the server without any error code . 
I was not able to find any error log information associated with it

```
131014 20:32:05 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted
131014 20:51:43 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted
131014 20:51:44 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted
```

When i checked the grid monitoring site it was displaying an alert

Message     The value of Temp. tables disk spills % is 26.67

However I have checked the tmp directory and the filesystem for available space  the results are as shown

```
 df -h /tmp
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md3              4.9G  768M  3.9G  17% /tmp

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1               20G  2.7G   16G  15% /
/dev/md5              112G  325M  105G   1% /var
/dev/md4              243G   37G  194G  16% /mysql_backup
/dev/md3              4.9G  768M  3.9G  17% /tmp
/dev/md2              291G   36G  241G  13% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/md0              996M   57M  888M   7% /boot
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Should i allocate more space for the /tmp . Kindly provide some suggestions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165112/mysql-error-sort-aborted